# Data acquisition and processing from Project Gutenberg

Tags: python, wordpress-gutenberg

I try process top-downloaded public domain ebooks from Project Gutenberg.
firt: Create a variant of the web crawler which is intended to download the top-k most
downloaded ebooks of the last 30 days from Project Gutenberg in .TXT format.
second: Using the crawler, download the top-20 ebooks (k=20). Report the names and addresses of
the books.
third: Use the processing pipeline described on the lecture to tokenize and lemmatize the
downloaded books.
four: Create a unified vocabulary from the ebooks; report the top-100 words.

First hint: the top-100 downloaded books of the last 30 days Project Gutenberg are listed on the site. In your answer, report the required statistics as well as your program code.
Second hint: Sometimes domain-specific processing is needed. Here, project Gutenberg ebooks include a header-text in the beginning and a footer-text (license description) at the end. For best results, you can modify the processing code to add a domain-specific processing step that removes the header and footer texts from each ebook.

How to do it:
• The header-text ends with a line "*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG
EBOOK ???????? ***", and the footer-text (license description) starts with a line "***
END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK ???????? ***", where ???????? is the
name of the ebook. The actual book content is between these lines.
• Once you have read in the text string of an ebook, you can find the location of "*** START
OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK", and then find the next newline - the book
content starts after that. Similarly, you can find the location of "*** END OF THIS
PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK" - the book content ends before that.
• Use Python's find function mytextstring.find(mysubstring,startindex,endindex) where
mytextstring is the string where you want to search, mysubstring is the string you want to
find, startindex is a zero-based index of where to start looking, and endindex is the final
index where you want to look. The function returns the index where the substring was found
(or -1 if it was not found).
• Once you have found the start and end indices of the content of the ebook, you can just take
that substring as your book content: mybookcontent = mytextstring[startindex:endindex]

I get those links but not the right books last 30 days

```py
import re
from os.path import join
from os import makedirs
from urllib.request import urlopen
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# download html and return parsed doc or None on error
def download_url(urlpath):
    try:
        # open a connection to the server
        with urlopen(urlpath, timeout=3) as connection:
            # read the contents of the html doc
            return connection.read()
    except:
        # bad url, socket timeout, http forbidden, etc.
        return None

# decode downloaded html and extract all <a href=""> links
def get_urls_from_html(content):
    # decode the provided content as ascii text
    html = content.decode('utf-8')
    # parse the document as best we can
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    # find all all of the <a href=""> tags in the document
    atags = soup.find_all('a')
    # get all links from a tags
    return [tag.get('href') for tag in atags]

# return all book unique identifiers from a list of raw links
def get_book_identifiers(links):
    # define a url pattern we are looking for
    pattern = re.compile('/ebooks/[0-9]+')
    # process the list of links for those that match the pattern
    books = set()
    for link in links:
        # check of the link matches the pattern
        if not pattern.match(link):
            continue
        # extract the book id from /ebooks/nnn
        book_id = link[8:]
        # store in the set, only keep unique ids
        books.add(book_id)
    return books

# download one book from project gutenberg
def download_book(book_id, save_path):
    # construct the download url
    url = f'https://www.gutenberg.org/files/{book_id}/{book_id}-0.txt'
    # download the content
    data = download_url(url)
    if data is None:
        return f'Failed to download {url}'
    # create local path
    save_file = join(save_path, f'{book_id}.txt')
    # save book to file
    with open(save_file, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(data)
    return f'Saved {save_file}'

# download all top books from project gutenberg
def download_all_books(url, save_path):
    # download the page that lists top books
    data = download_url(url)
    print(f'.downloaded {url}')
    # extract all links from the page
    links = get_urls_from_html(data)
    print(f'.found {len(links)} links on the page')
    # retrieve all unique book ids
    book_ids = get_book_identifiers(links)
    print(f'.found {len(book_ids)} unique book ids')
    # create the save directory if needed
    makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)
    # download and save each book in turn
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(len(book_ids)) as exe:
        futures = [exe.submit(download_book, book, save_path) for book in book_ids]
        # report results as books are downloaded
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            # report the result messages
            print(future.result())
            
def dowload_top_100():



   data = download_url(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
    top_30=[i['href'] for i  in soup.find_all('ol')[4].find_all('a')]
    #h_tag = soup.find(id='books-last30')
    ol_tag = h_tag.next_sibling.next_sibling
    for a_tag in ol_tag.find_all('a'):
        m = re.match(r'(.*)(\(\d+\))', a_tag.text)
        book_name = m.group(1).strip()
        m = re.match(r'/ebooks/(\d+)', a_tag.get('href'))
        book_id = m.group(1)
        # ugh, I know this is ugly.
        url = base_url + '/'.join(list(book_id[:-1])) + '/' + book_id + '/' + book_id + '.txt'
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            # print 'Downloaded... ', file_name
            with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
                f.write(r.text.encode('UTF-8'))
        else:
            print ('Failed for ', book_id)

# entry point
URL = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/browse/scores/top'
DIR = 'books'
# download top books
download_all_books(URL, DIR)
```

Comment: Project Gutenberg explicitly forbids crawling and automated access. Be sure to read their guidelines: https://www.gutenberg.org/policy/robot_access.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy. Many books exist in up to three versions: xxx.zip, xxx-0.zip, and xxx-8.zip. There are also books with the string 'IMPROVED EDITION OF THIS TITLE' followed by yyy.zip.
The strings marking the start and end of the text exist in several variations. Here are the best strings I could find to mark the start and end of text, and there are a number of files I did not find a good end string for.

```
startstrings = (
'*** START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'***START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
' *** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'*** START OF PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'*** START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG ETEXT',
'*END THE SMALL PRINT!',
'*END*THE SMALL PRINT!',
'**END THE SMALL PRINT!',
'*SMALL PRINT! Ver',
'**The Project Gutenberg Etext',
'*****These eBooks Were Prepared By Thousands of Volunteers',
'This etext was produced by',
'SERVICE THAT CHARGES FOR DOWNLOAD TIME OR FOR MEMBERSHIP',
'Scanned by Dianne Bean',
'Copyright © Timothy E. Clontz 1999'
)
endstrings = (
'*** END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'***END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'End of the Project Gutenberg EBook',
'*** END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'END OF PROJECT GUTENBERG ETEXT',
'End of The Project Gutenberg Etext',
'End of the Project Gutenberg etext',
'End of Project Gutenberg Etext',
"End of Project Gutenberg's Etext",
' *** END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'      *** END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'       *** END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK',
'End of this Etext',
'End of this Project Gutenberg Etext',
'End of the Project Gutenberg Etext',
'End of The Project Gutenberg EBook',
'*** START: FULL LICENSE ***'
)
```

You do not need to use a web scraper. Project Gutenberg recommends [this method](https://www.gutenberg.org/help/mirroring.html)